# Change names and extensions of all the files and grouping them in linux

Tags: bash, grouping, file-extension

In this code i get the path of a folder from user and then i enter that path .
After that , i change names and extensions of all the files no matter what their names or extensions are .
I'm changing their names to "pic" with a counter starting from 1 until last file (to count how many files are there) and their extensions to jpg (for example).

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter Folder's Path :"
read path
cd $path

c=0
for file in *.*;do
mv "$file" "pic $((c=c+1)).jpg"
done
```

Now help me to make a directory for every (for example) 10 files and move those files (from 1 to 10 , 11 to 20 and ...) to that specific directory .

Comment: Lookup conditional statements in bash

Comment: what you want is rename all files to pic_{counter}.jpg in some assigned directory?

Comment: @baozilaji I renamed all the files with that code above , now I want to make directory for every 10 files and move them there . for example pic1 to pic10 goes to directory1 .

Answer (score 1):

Using `mapfile` aka `readarray` which is a *bash4+* feature.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -rp "Enter Folder's Path : " path
cd "$path" || exit

n=1
c=0

files=(*.*)

while mapfile -n10 -d '' -t array && ((${#array[*]})); do
  mkdir -pv "directory$n" || exit
  for file in "${array[@]}"; do
    mv -v "$file" "directory$n/pic$c.jpg" || exit
    ((c++))
  done
  ((n++))
done < <(printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}")
```

---

The script above will do the following:

- It will rename the files with the desired naming scheme with an increment.
- It will create a directory with the desired naming scheme with an increment
- Move the files by 10 pairs per directory.
- If there are remaining files (less than 10) those files will go on the last directory. Like if you have `105` files, the remaining 5 files will go inside the `directory11` the rest in directories 1 to 10 in pairs per directory.

The `nullglob` should be enabled `shopt -s nullglob`

Also a check if the directory is not empty should be added.

Also a check if you're renaming directories too.

---

An example of how the script works in action.

First create some dummy files somewhere, say in `/tmp`

```
[[ -d /tmp ]] && mkdir -p /tmp/testing/ && touch /tmp/testing/{1..21}.{pdf,csv,mp3,txt,rpm}
```

Now check the created dummy files.

```
ls /tmp/testing
```

Output

```
10.csv  11.csv  12.csv  13.csv  14.csv  15.csv  16.csv  17.csv  18.csv  19.csv  1.csv  20.csv  21.csv  2.csv  3.csv  4.csv  5.csv  6.csv  7.csv  8.csv  9.csv
10.mp3  11.mp3  12.mp3  13.mp3  14.mp3  15.mp3  16.mp3  17.mp3  18.mp3  19.mp3  1.mp3  20.mp3  21.mp3  2.mp3  3.mp3  4.mp3  5.mp3  6.mp3  7.mp3  8.mp3  9.mp3
10.pdf  11.pdf  12.pdf  13.pdf  14.pdf  15.pdf  16.pdf  17.pdf  18.pdf  19.pdf  1.pdf  20.pdf  21.pdf  2.pdf  3.pdf  4.pdf  5.pdf  6.pdf  7.pdf  8.pdf  9.pdf
10.rpm  11.rpm  12.rpm  13.rpm  14.rpm  15.rpm  16.rpm  17.rpm  18.rpm  19.rpm  1.rpm  20.rpm  21.rpm  2.rpm  3.rpm  4.rpm  5.rpm  6.rpm  7.rpm  8.rpm  9.rpm
10.txt  11.txt  12.txt  13.txt  14.txt  15.txt  16.txt  17.txt  18.txt  19.txt  1.txt  20.txt  21.txt  2.txt  3.txt  4.txt  5.txt  6.txt  7.txt  8.txt  9.txt
```

---

Run the script. (Assuming your script name is `myscript.sh` and it is in the current `pwd`)

```
bash ./myscript.sh
```

Output

```
 Enter Folder's Path :
```

---

Key in the directory with the dummy files.

```
 Enter Folder's Path : /tmp/testing
```

---

Output

```
mkdir: created directory 'directory1'
renamed '10.csv' -> 'directory1/pic0.jpg'
renamed '10.mp3' -> 'directory1/pic1.jpg'
renamed '10.pdf' -> 'directory1/pic2.jpg'
renamed '10.rpm' -> 'directory1/pic3.jpg'
renamed '10.txt' -> 'directory1/pic4.jpg'
renamed '11.csv' -> 'directory1/pic5.jpg'
renamed '11.mp3' -> 'directory1/pic6.jpg'
renamed '11.pdf' -> 'directory1/pic7.jpg'
renamed '11.rpm' -> 'directory1/pic8.jpg'
renamed '11.txt' -> 'directory1/pic9.jpg'
mkdir: created directory 'directory2'
renamed '12.csv' -> 'directory2/pic10.jpg'
renamed '12.mp3' -> 'directory2/pic11.jpg'
renamed '12.pdf' -> 'directory2/pic12.jpg'
renamed '12.rpm' -> 'directory2/pic13.jpg'
renamed '12.txt' -> 'directory2/pic14.jpg'
renamed '13.csv' -> 'directory2/pic15.jpg'
renamed '13.mp3' -> 'directory2/pic16.jpg'
renamed '13.pdf' -> 'directory2/pic17.jpg'
renamed '13.rpm' -> 'directory2/pic18.jpg'
renamed '13.txt' -> 'directory2/pic19.jpg'
mkdir: created directory 'directory3'
renamed '14.csv' -> 'directory3/pic20.jpg'
renamed '14.mp3' -> 'directory3/pic21.jpg'
renamed '14.pdf' -> 'directory3/pic22.jpg'
renamed '14.rpm' -> 'directory3/pic23.jpg'
renamed '14.txt' -> 'directory3/pic24.jpg'
renamed '15.csv' -> 'directory3/pic25.jpg'
renamed '15.mp3' -> 'directory3/pic26.jpg'
renamed '15.pdf' -> 'directory3/pic27.jpg'
renamed '15.rpm' -> 'directory3/pic28.jpg'
renamed '15.txt' -> 'directory3/pic29.jpg'
mkdir: created directory 'directory4'
renamed '16.csv' -> 'directory4/pic30.jpg'
renamed '16.mp3' -> 'directory4/pic31.jpg'
renamed '16.pdf' -> 'directory4/pic32.jpg'
renamed '16.rpm' -> 'directory4/pic33.jpg'
renamed '16.txt' -> 'directory4/pic34.jpg'
renamed '17.csv' -> 'directory4/pic35.jpg'
renamed '17.mp3' -> 'directory4/pic36.jpg'
renamed '17.pdf' -> 'directory4/pic37.jpg'
renamed '17.rpm' -> 'directory4/pic38.jpg'
renamed '17.txt' -> 'directory4/pic39.jpg'
mkdir: created directory 'directory5'
renamed '18.csv' -> 'directory5/pic40.jpg'
renamed '18.mp3' -> 'directory5/pic41.jpg'
renamed '18.pdf' -> 'directory5/pic42.jpg'
renamed '18.rpm' -> 'directory5/pic43.jpg'
renamed '18.txt' -> 'directory5/pic44.jpg'
renamed '19.csv' -> 'directory5/pic45.jpg'
renamed '19.mp3' -> 'directory5/pic46.jpg'
renamed '19.pdf' -> 'directory5/pic47.jpg'
renamed '19.rpm' -> 'directory5/pic48.jpg'
renamed '19.txt' -> 'directory5/pic49.jpg'
mkdir: created directory 'directory6'
renamed '1.csv' -> 'directory6/pic50.jpg'
renamed '1.mp3' -> 'directory6/pic51.jpg'
renamed '1.pdf' -> 'directory6/pic52.jpg'
renamed '1.rpm' -> 'directory6/pic53.jpg'
renamed '1.txt' -> 'directory6/pic54.jpg'
renamed '20.csv' -> 'directory6/pic55.jpg'
renamed '20.mp3' -> 'directory6/pic56.jpg'
renamed '20.pdf' -> 'directory6/pic57.jpg'
renamed '20.rpm' -> 'directory6/pic58.jpg'
renamed '20.txt' -> 'directory6/pic59.jpg'
mkdir: created directory 'directory7'
renamed '21.csv' -> 'directory7/pic60.jpg'
renamed '21.mp3' -> 'directory7/pic61.jpg'
renamed '21.pdf' -> 'directory7/pic62.jpg'
renamed '21.rpm' -> 'directory7/pic63.jpg'
renamed '21.txt' -> 'directory7/pic64.jpg'
renamed '2.csv' -> 'directory7/pic65.jpg'
renamed '2.mp3' -> 'directory7/pic66.jpg'
renamed '2.pdf' -> 'directory7/pic67.jpg'
renamed '2.rpm' -> 'directory7/pic68.jpg'
renamed '2.txt' -> 'directory7/pic69.jpg'
mkdir: created directory 'directory8'
renamed '3.csv' -> 'directory8/pic70.jpg'
renamed '3.mp3' -> 'directory8/pic71.jpg'
renamed '3.pdf' -> 'directory8/pic72.jpg'
renamed '3.rpm' -> 'directory8/pic73.jpg'
renamed '3.txt' -> 'directory8/pic74.jpg'
renamed '4.csv' -> 'directory8/pic75.jpg'
renamed '4.mp3' -> 'directory8/pic76.jpg'
renamed '4.pdf' -> 'directory8/pic77.jpg'
renamed '4.rpm' -> 'directory8/pic78.jpg'
renamed '4.txt' -> 'directory8/pic79.jpg'
mkdir: created directory 'directory9'
renamed '5.csv' -> 'directory9/pic80.jpg'
renamed '5.mp3' -> 'directory9/pic81.jpg'
renamed '5.pdf' -> 'directory9/pic82.jpg'
renamed '5.rpm' -> 'directory9/pic83.jpg'
renamed '5.txt' -> 'directory9/pic84.jpg'
renamed '6.csv' -> 'directory9/pic85.jpg'
renamed '6.mp3' -> 'directory9/pic86.jpg'
renamed '6.pdf' -> 'directory9/pic87.jpg'
renamed '6.rpm' -> 'directory9/pic88.jpg'
renamed '6.txt' -> 'directory9/pic89.jpg'
mkdir: created directory 'directory10'
renamed '7.csv' -> 'directory10/pic90.jpg'
renamed '7.mp3' -> 'directory10/pic91.jpg'
renamed '7.pdf' -> 'directory10/pic92.jpg'
renamed '7.rpm' -> 'directory10/pic93.jpg'
renamed '7.txt' -> 'directory10/pic94.jpg'
renamed '8.csv' -> 'directory10/pic95.jpg'
renamed '8.mp3' -> 'directory10/pic96.jpg'
renamed '8.pdf' -> 'directory10/pic97.jpg'
renamed '8.rpm' -> 'directory10/pic98.jpg'
renamed '8.txt' -> 'directory10/pic99.jpg'
mkdir: created directory 'directory11'
renamed '9.csv' -> 'directory11/pic100.jpg'
renamed '9.mp3' -> 'directory11/pic101.jpg'
renamed '9.pdf' -> 'directory11/pic102.jpg'
renamed '9.rpm' -> 'directory11/pic103.jpg'
renamed '9.txt' -> 'directory11/pic104.jpg'
```

---

Check the files in their directories.

```
ls /tmp/testing/directory[0-9]*/
```

Output

```
/tmp/testing/directory1/:
pic0.jpg  pic1.jpg  pic2.jpg  pic3.jpg  pic4.jpg  pic5.jpg  pic6.jpg  pic7.jpg  pic8.jpg  pic9.jpg

/tmp/testing/directory10/:
pic90.jpg  pic91.jpg  pic92.jpg  pic93.jpg  pic94.jpg  pic95.jpg  pic96.jpg  pic97.jpg  pic98.jpg  pic99.jpg

/tmp/testing/directory11/:
pic100.jpg  pic101.jpg  pic102.jpg  pic103.jpg  pic104.jpg

/tmp/testing/directory2/:
pic10.jpg  pic11.jpg  pic12.jpg  pic13.jpg  pic14.jpg  pic15.jpg  pic16.jpg  pic17.jpg  pic18.jpg  pic19.jpg

/tmp/testing/directory3/:
pic20.jpg  pic21.jpg  pic22.jpg  pic23.jpg  pic24.jpg  pic25.jpg  pic26.jpg  pic27.jpg  pic28.jpg  pic29.jpg

/tmp/testing/directory4/:
pic30.jpg  pic31.jpg  pic32.jpg  pic33.jpg  pic34.jpg  pic35.jpg  pic36.jpg  pic37.jpg  pic38.jpg  pic39.jpg

/tmp/testing/directory5/:
pic40.jpg  pic41.jpg  pic42.jpg  pic43.jpg  pic44.jpg  pic45.jpg  pic46.jpg  pic47.jpg  pic48.jpg  pic49.jpg

/tmp/testing/directory6/:
pic50.jpg  pic51.jpg  pic52.jpg  pic53.jpg  pic54.jpg  pic55.jpg  pic56.jpg  pic57.jpg  pic58.jpg  pic59.jpg

/tmp/testing/directory7/:
pic60.jpg  pic61.jpg  pic62.jpg  pic63.jpg  pic64.jpg  pic65.jpg  pic66.jpg  pic67.jpg  pic68.jpg  pic69.jpg

/tmp/testing/directory8/:
pic70.jpg  pic71.jpg  pic72.jpg  pic73.jpg  pic74.jpg  pic75.jpg  pic76.jpg  pic77.jpg  pic78.jpg  pic79.jpg

/tmp/testing/directory9/:
pic80.jpg  pic81.jpg  pic82.jpg  pic83.jpg  pic84.jpg  pic85.jpg  pic86.jpg  pic87.jpg  pic88.jpg  pic89.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what you needs I think.

```
COUNT=0
find test -name "pic_*.jpg"|tr -s '_' '.'|awk -F'.' '{print $(NF-2),$(NF-1),$(NF)}'|sort -nk 2|awk '{print $1"_"$2"."$3}'|while read line;do
        echo $line
        COUNT=$((COUNT+1))
        echo $COUNT
        DIR=$(($COUNT / 10 + 1))
        echo $DIR
        mkdir -p dir$DIR
        mv $line dir$DIR
done
```

depends on:

all files that saves in test directory and name as pic_xxx.jpg

Comment: and does not have any directory which contains the symbol '_'